# ASP.net 5 MVC 6 bower.json and project.json disappear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2015, bower

Is there a reason why bower.json and project.json disappear from the Solution Explorer after closing an ASP.net 5 Web Project? You can click the "Show Hidden Files" icon to display them, but I want them to be part of the project. With the package Intellisense, the json files are much quicker than the clunky Bower tooling.

Comment: After Show Hidden Files, to permanently include them, right click on the file and select "Show in Solution Explorer". The text might vary slightly depending on which version of VS you have and the text will change from Show to Hide once you have selected it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve this you have to remove the **DnxInvisibleContent** tag inside ItemGroup in the **xproj file**.

From:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="bower.json" />
    <DnxInvisibleContent Include="package.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

To:

```
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
```

They should appear in your solution explorer and you'll be free to edit them as you wish.

Let me know if this doesn't help.

Comment: This works for the .NET Core 1.0 RTM release in VS2015. Thanks